# Can't access data from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

In my content script I have done following :

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
  localStorage["options"] = "yes";
}
```

If I try to access this localStorage["options"] in my options.html page. it is giving me ***undefined*** error.

What can I do to access this content?

**My Requirement :** I need to get some data from the page source of a specific page and store it in localStorage. Then i need to process this data in my options.html page.

**Edit :** I am able to access the localStorage created in the options page in my background page.
But I can't access localStorage created in content script in the options page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not a bug. You've hit a limitation in Chrome's extension sandboxing. Background and options pages don't share cookies, localStorage, or any other JS persistence that you would expect to work on the same "domain" (read: extension).

The solution is to use messaging, as described in the docs:
[Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html)

Comment: holy crap !!!  :( :(
@Bloudermilk ... Thanks for this
I need to call a method from content script when I click on Options Page on browser extension icon.
Can something be done for this?

Comment: You're welcome! What you're describing is possible with messaging (see docs above).

Comment: @Blaudermilk.... I need some data from a page just before moving into the options page. How can it be possible?

Comment: @Blaudermilk... Is there any event which is called on clicking options links on browser extension icon.

Comment: @Chaitnya Your comments are beyond the scope of this question. Please post new questions :)

Comment: Got Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165553/how-to-create-a-dynamic-options-page-in-chrome-extension