# How to create a dynamic options page in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an options page with dynamically created options.

I am extracting some data from a web page' source using my content script and I want that data to be displayed in the options page. How could I send that data to my options page?

I have used **localStorage** in content script but that is not accessible in options page.

**localStorage** is accessible in background page and content script if created in options page. But if I am creating it in content script, it is not accessible in options page.

How can I do this?

Comment: The problem is not included in title. You set issue as dynamic options creation but You asked for getting data from content to options which is confusing.
I still cannot find solution for my problem (and from Your title)
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution.

I just extracted the data in my content script,then, I communicated with my background_page and sent the data to the background_page with the help of [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html). In my background_page I stored the data in the localStorage which is accessible in my Options page. Little tricky but working successfully.

Answer (score 6):

Since the pages do not share resources, you need to use this:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Quoting from it:

> Communication between extensions and their content scripts works by
>   using message passing. Either side can listen for messages sent from
>   the other end, and respond on the same channel. A message can contain
>   any valid JSON object (null, boolean, number, string, array, or
>   object). There is a simple API for one-time requests and a more
>   complex API that allows you to have long-lived connections for
>   exchanging multiple messages with a shared context. It is also
>   possible to send a message to another extension if you know its ID,
>   which is covered in the cross-extension messages section.